# Other ways of hiding a div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a jQuery which toggles a div on click.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#showmenu').click(function() {
    $('#showmenu').text($('.sidebarmenu').is(':visible') ? 'Show Menu' : 'Hide Menu');
    $('.sidebarmenu').toggle("slide");
}); 
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/KEsBR/2/)

How can I do the same without using

```
display:none;
```

??

Comment: What's wrong with `display: none`?

Comment: It is breaking some other code which I cannot post here. When I remove display:none; the code works fine.  But I want the div to  be hidden on load.

Comment: Maybe you should improve the other code instead of trying to solve around the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at a offset based solution

```
<button id="showmenu" type="button">Show menu</button></div>
<div class="sidebarmenu" style="position: absolute; left: -200000px">

    Can the button value change to "show" or "hide"
</div>
```

then

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#showmenu').click(function() {
        var hidden = $('.sidebarmenu').data('hidden');
        $('#showmenu').text(hidden ? 'Show Menu' : 'Hide Menu');
        if(hidden){
            $('.sidebarmenu').css({
                position: 'absolute',
                left: -200000
            })
        } else {
            $('.sidebarmenu').css({
                position: '',
                left: 0
            })
        }
        $('.sidebarmenu').data("hidden", !hidden);
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3R4Pn/)

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `visibility:hidden;` css property which work same.

There is another alternative which is `opacity` set `opacity:0`

Comment: @Itay on client side it perform same...isn't it..?

Comment: Nope. [What is the difference between visibility:hidden and display:none?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133051/what-is-the-difference-between-visibilityhidden-and-displaynone)

Answer (score 0):

not sure if i got your question .. but i gues you can use `hide()`.

```
 $('.sidebarmenu').hide();
```

inside your document.ready `$(document).ready(function() {` function

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/KEsBR/5/)

Answer (score 0):

You can also place this using `.show()` and `.hide()`

```
($('#showmenu').is(':visible')) ? $('.sidebarmenu').show() 
                                : $('.sidebarmenu').hide();
```

And on page load hide the div like

```
$('.sidebarmenu').hide();
```

See the [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/KEsBR/6/)

Comment: but how do I hide the div on load?

Comment: @Bittu add `$('.sidebarmenu').hide()` on page load

Comment: Yes @Bittu...If you see my fiddle ,you can find that.

Comment: It'll probably cause the same problems as `display: none`, for it does the exact same

Answer (score 0):

To hide div u can use `Visible="false"` and to show use `Visible="true"`

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#showmenu').click(function() {
    $('#showmenu').text($('.sidebarmenu').is(':visible') ? 'Show Menu' : 'Hide Menu');
    $('.sidebarmenu').toggle("show");
}); 
});
```